# Hudson + SVN Copy only incremental files to the workspace

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hudson

I am using Hudson with SVN. Now when i run the build, it will copy all the files from the branch to my working directory. I need only the files modified/newlyadded as part of the build. The build should copy only the incremental units to the working directory. How can i achieve this. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The first checkout will be a full checkout/copy.

All subsequent checkouts, will only pull changes since the previous checkout. For this to work, in your SCM portion of the job configuration, you need to make sure that **Check-out Strategy** is set to **Use 'svn update' as much as possible**

Comment: I dont need all those base files. Need only the incremental files in the working directory. please advice

Comment: To have incremental files, you need to have a base first. Otherwise, what you are incrementing on?